# Replacing Bootstap svg placeholder image

Tags: html, css, django

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/carousel/

I'm following along with this and implementing this in Django.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<!-- saved from url=(0052)https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/ -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.82.0">
    <title>Carousel Template · Bootstrap v5.0</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/">

    

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="{% static 'home/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Favicons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
<link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
<link rel="manifest" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#7952b3">
<link rel="icon" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">


    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }
    </style>

    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template --><link href="{% static 'home/css/carousel.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <script data-dapp-detection="">!function(){let e=!1;function n(){if(!e){const n=document.createElement("meta");n.name="dapp-detected",document.head.appendChild(n),e=!0}}if(window.hasOwnProperty("ethereum")){if(window.__disableDappDetectionInsertion=!0,void 0===window.ethereum)return;n()}else{var t=window.ethereum;Object.defineProperty(window,"ethereum",{configurable:!0,enumerable:!1,set:function(e){window.__disableDappDetectionInsertion||n(),t=e},get:function(){if(!window.__disableDappDetectionInsertion){const e=arguments.callee;e&&e.caller&&e.caller.toString&&-1!==e.caller.toString().indexOf("getOwnPropertyNames")||n()}return t}})}}();</script></head>
  <body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1002.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">
    
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Carousel</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-label="Slide 1" aria-current="true"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2" class=""></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3" class=""></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect></svg>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-start">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide of the carousel.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Sign up today</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect></svg>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide of the carousel.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Learn more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect></svg>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-end">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide of this carousel.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Browse gallery</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>



  <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
  ================================================== -->
  <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

  <div class="container marketing">

    <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>

        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the three columns of text below the carousel. This is the first column.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">View details »</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>

        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Another exciting bit of representative placeholder content. This time, we've moved on to the second column.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">View details »</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>

        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>And lastly this, the third column of representative placeholder content.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">View details »</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->


    <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It’ll blow your mind.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Some great placeholder content for the first featurette here. Imagine some exciting prose here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>

      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it’s that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Another featurette? Of course. More placeholder content here to give you an idea of how this layout would work with some actual real-world content in place.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>

      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">And yes, this is the last block of representative placeholder content. Again, not really intended to be actually read, simply here to give you a better view of what this would look like with some actual content. Your content.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>

      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->

  </div><!-- /.container -->


  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer class="container">
    <p class="float-end"><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Back to top</a></p>
    <p>© 2017–2021 Company, Inc. · <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Privacy</a> · <a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/#">Terms</a></p>
  </footer>
</main>


    <script src="{% static 'home/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      
  

</body></html>
```

It sounds like a stupid question and it probably is, but how to I replace the background images in the svg class?

That is, this block of code. There doesn't seem to be documentation anywhere on it.

```
<svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Infuriating, isn't it... Here's how I solved the problem.
Copy the line you wish to edit into notepad (for reference); in my case it was..

```
<svg class="bd-placeholder-img figure-img img-fluid rounded" width="400" height="300"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 400x300"
    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
    <title>Placeholder</title>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">400x300</text>
</svg>
```

Simply treat `xmlns=` as if it is `src="yourimageaddress.svg"`.
For me this worked to display the image and you can try that and then (if you're brave enough) try removing some of the other attributes for the placeholder where required.

I was editing the placeholder from the bootstrap cheatsheet that can be found in this folder in getbootstrap (`bootstrap-5.0.0-beta1-examples/cheatsheet/index.html#images`)